# $\left\lfloor\frac{8n+13}{25}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n-12-\left\lfloor\frac{n-17}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor$ is independent of $n$

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> If $n$ is a positive integer, prove that
> $$\left\lfloor\frac{8n+13}{25}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n-12-\left\lfloor\frac{n-17}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor$$
> is independent of $n$.

Taking
$$f(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{8n+13}{25}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n-12-\left\lfloor\frac{n-17}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor$$
I could prove that
$$f(n+25)=f(n)$$
But, I have no idea how to show
$$f(n+k)=f(n)\\\forall k\in \{1,2,\dots 24\}$$
Of course, we can check these *finite number* of cases by force. But is there any other elegant method to handle this?

Comment: It is equivalent to prove

$$\left\lfloor \frac{8n+13}{25} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{n-a}{3} \right\rfloor, \; a = \left\lfloor\frac{n-17}{25}\right\rfloor, \; n \in \mathbb{Z}^{>0}$$

Comment: @BeKind of course, but how does that help?

Comment: If you let $n= 25k + r; 17\le r < 42$ then $\left\lfloor\frac{n-12-\left\lfloor\frac{n-17}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor= 8k + 4$.  Then $[\frac {8n+13}{25}]= [8k +\frac{8r+13}{25}]$.  Can show the the margin of error overlaps.

Comment: But this does not work. 
If $r=17$, then $\left \lfloor 8k+\frac{8r+13}{25} \right \rfloor = 8k+5$.
Yet when $r=24$, $\left \lfloor 8k+\frac{8r+13}{25} \right \rfloor = 8k+8$.
The difference from $8k+4$will not be the same.

Comment: Hint: from a quick glance it looks like it arises from something like below

$$\begin{align} \left\lfloor\frac{1}c\,\left\lfloor\frac{1}d\,(can\,+\,b)\, \right \rfloor  \right\rfloor &= \left\lfloor 
 \frac{1}d(an+\lfloor b/c \rfloor)\right\rfloor \\[.6em]
\Rightarrow\ \left\lfloor\frac{1}{3}\left\lfloor\frac{1}{25}(24n\!+\!41) \right \rfloor  \right\rfloor &= \left\lfloor 
 \frac{1}{25}(8n+ 13 )\right\rfloor \end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a variation which is also related to [Bill Dubuque's hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4489162/left-lfloor-frac8n1325-right-rfloor-left-lfloor-fracn-12-left-lfloor-f#comment9417386_4489162). We want to show that
\begin{align*}
f(n)&=\left\lfloor\frac{8n+13}{25}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n-12-\left\lfloor\frac{n-17}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor\\
&=\left\lfloor\frac{8n+13}{25}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n-\left\lfloor\frac{n-17}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor+4
\end{align*}
is independent from $n$. Since
\begin{align*}
f(0)&=\left\lfloor\frac{13}{25}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{-\left\lfloor\frac{-17}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor+4\\
&=0-0+4=4
\end{align*}
we claim the following is valid for all non-negative integers $n$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\left\lfloor\frac{8n+13}{25}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{n-\left\lfloor\frac{n-17}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We start with the right-hand side of (1) and obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left\lfloor\frac{n-\left\lfloor\frac{n-17}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor}
> &=\left\lfloor\frac{-\left\lfloor\frac{-24n-17}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor
> =\left\lfloor\frac{\left\lceil\frac{24n+17}{25}\right\rceil}{3}\right\rfloor\tag{2.1}\\
> &=\left\lfloor\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{24n+41}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor
> =\left\lfloor\frac{24n+41}{75}\right\rfloor\tag{2.2}\\
> &=\left\lfloor\frac{24n+39}{75}\right\rfloor\tag{2.3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left\lfloor\frac{8n+13}{25}\right\rfloor}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2.1) we bring $n$ into the inner floor symbol and use the *[rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Relations_among_the_functions)*
  $$\lfloor -x\rfloor=-\lceil x\rceil$$
- In (2.2) we use *[the rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281710)*
  \begin{align*}
  \left\lceil \frac{n}{m} \right\rceil =\left \lfloor \frac{n+m-1}{m} \right\rfloor
  \end{align*}
  and also the *[nested division rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Nested_divisions)*
  \begin{align*}
  \left\lfloor\frac{\left\lfloor x/m\right\rfloor}{n}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{mn}\right\rfloor
  \end{align*}
- In (2.3) we can check for $0\leq n<25$ the validity of $\left\lfloor\frac{24n+41}{75}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{24n+39}{75}\right\rfloor$. We can alternatively note the difference between these two expressions inside the floor symbols is $\frac{2}{75}$. So, *different* natural numbers would occur, iff there is a natural number $m$ with
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{24n+39}{75}=m-\frac{1}{75}\qquad\quad\text{and}\qquad\quad\frac{24n+41}{75}=m+\frac{1}{75}
  \end{align*}
  This is equivalent with the existence of a solution of the linear congruence relation
  \begin{align*}
  24n+41&\equiv 1\pmod{75}\\
  24n&\equiv 35\pmod{75}\\
  \end{align*}
  But this has *[no solution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearCongruenceEquation.html)*, since
  \begin{align*}
  35&\not\equiv 0\pmod{\gcd(24,75)}\\
  35&\not\equiv 0\pmod{3}\\
  \end{align*}

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the method I hinted in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4489162/left-lfloor-frac8n1325-right-rfloor-left-lfloor-fracn-12-left-lfloor-f#comment9417386_4489162) on the question. The "nested division rule" is proved very simply in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/172914/242) (I meant to link that in said comment). Good work!

Comment: @BillDubuque: Many thanks for the nice comment and the references.

Comment: I added the link to your answer (else readers might not know what it refers to). Note that you can't ping users in answers using `@` (luckily I discovered your answer anyhow).

Comment: @BillDubuque: Ok, I see. Thanks for the hint. :-)

Comment: This is the trickiest one among the batch. Thanks a lot (+1)!

Comment: @SayanDutta: You're welcome and thanks for the credit. :-)

Comment: @Sayan You may find of interest the short ptoof I posted using the universal property of floor. This avoids requiring any knowledge of floor laws (except the definition).

Answer (score 5):

Using $\color{darkorange}{\rm UF}$ = [universal property of floor](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/172914/242), i.e. $\ k\le \lfloor r\rfloor\!\!\iff\! k\le r;\ $ $\ \color{#90f}{k \le -\lfloor r\rfloor\!\!\iff\! k\!-\!1< -r},\ $
the proof reduces to trivial algebra, i.e. apply $\,\lfloor(r\!-\!12)/3\rfloor^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\! = \lfloor r/3\rfloor - 4\,$ followed by below.

$\begin{align} {\bf Theorem}\ \quad \lfloor \color{#0a0}{\tfrac{1}{25}(8n+3)}\rfloor  &= \lfloor \tfrac{1}{3}(n - \lfloor(n-17)/25\rfloor)\rfloor,\ \ {\rm for}\ \ n\in\Bbb Z\\[.4em]
{\bf Proof}\ \  {\rm for}\ \ k\in\Bbb Z\!:\  \ \qquad k&\ \le\, \tfrac{1}{3}(n - \lfloor(n-17)/25\rfloor)\\[.2em]
\iff\ 3k-n&\,\le\,\ \ \ \ \ \ \  -\lfloor(n-17)/25\rfloor\\[.3em]
\iff\ 3k-n &\,\le\, (-n+41)/25,\ \ {\rm by\ Lemma\ below}\\[.3em]
\smash[t]{\overset{\times\ 25}\iff}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 75k &\,\le\,\  24n+41\\[.3em]
\smash[t]{\overset{\div\,3}\iff}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \,25k &\,\le\ \ \ 8n+ 13,\ \ {\rm by}\ \ 25k\in\Bbb Z\\[.2em]
\iff\qquad\ \ \ k &\,\le \color{#0a0}{\tfrac{1}{25}(8n+3)}
\end{align}$

**Lemma** $\ \ \ \   \color{#90f}{j \,\le\, -\lfloor a/b\rfloor}\iff j\!\color{darkorange}{-\!1}\le (-a\!\color{darkorange}{-\!1})/b,\ \ {\rm for}\,\ \color{#c00}{b>0}\,$ (wlog), $\,a,b\in\Bbb Z$
**Pf:** $
 \overset{\rm\color{darkorange}{UF}}\iff\! \color{#90f}{j\!-\!1 < {-}a/b}\!\!\underset{\color{#c00}{\times\ b}}\iff\! b(j\!\color{darkorange}{-\!1})\!\,\le -a\!\color{darkorange}{-\!1}\ $ [by $\  m<n\!\iff m\le n\!\color{darkorange}{-\!1}$]

Comment: This is an alternative approach to my [hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4489162/left-lfloor-frac8n1325-right-rfloor-left-lfloor-fracn-12-left-lfloor-f/4491445#comment9417386_4489162) that does not require knowledge of floor laws (I did intend the hint to use floor laws, but that way has since been posted). This universal approach often proves handy, so it deserves wider exposure.

Comment: Interesting and instructive approach. (+1)

Comment: Beautiful one (+1)!

Answer (score 4):

This is an amendment of my solution inspired by fleablood's comment:

To simplify the expression $\left \lfloor \frac{n-17}{25} \right \rfloor$, let $n-17=25k+r$ i.e. $n=25k+r+17$ where $0 \le r \le 24$.

Then

$$\left\lfloor \frac{8n+13}{25}\right \rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac{8(25k+r+17)+13}{25} \right\rfloor = 8k+5+\left\lfloor \frac{8r+24}{25} \right\rfloor$$

and  $$\left\lfloor \frac{n-12-\left\lfloor \frac{n-17}{25} \right\rfloor}{3} \right\rfloor =\left\lfloor \frac{25k+r+17-12-\left\lfloor \frac{25k+r+17-17}{25}\right \rfloor}{3} \right\rfloor=8k+1+\left\lfloor \frac{r+2}{3}\right \rfloor $$

The job is done if we can prove that

$$\left\lfloor \frac{8r+24}{25}\right \rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{r+2}{3} \right\rfloor $$ is independent of $r$ when $0 \le r \le 24$

For this, put $r=3m+h$ where $0 \le h \le 2$ and $0 \le r \le 24$.

It is not difficult to check that
$$\left\lfloor \frac{8r+24}{25}\right \rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{r+2}{3} \right\rfloor  $$
under the said conditions.

Comment: It's still brute forcing a little bit, but that's fine I guess (+1)

Comment: Basically there are only 3 cases to consider: $h=0$, $h=1$ and $h=2$

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that involves checking considerably fewer than $24$ cases, with it also having the advantage that it helps to provide a somewhat intuitive explanation of why the relation holds.

First, note that $\left\lfloor\frac{n-12-\left\lfloor\frac{n-17}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{n-\left\lfloor\frac{n-17}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor - 4$. Since $-4$ doesn't affect whether or not your $f(n)$ is always a constant, I'll ignore it. Next, set

$$g(n) = \left\lfloor\frac{8n+13}{25}\right\rfloor, \; \; h(n) = \left\lfloor\frac{n-\left\lfloor\frac{n-17}{25}\right\rfloor}{3}\right\rfloor, \; \; f_1(n) = g(n) - h(n) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

As you've indicated, $f(n)$ (and, thus, my $f_1(n)$) has a period of $25$. Thus, we just need to prove that $f_1(n)$ doesn't change for any consecutive set of $25$ integers, so induction can then be used for any larger values, & also smaller values, to show $f_1(n)$ is constant for all integers, not only just the positive ones.

Note the numerators inside the floor functions in $g(n)$ and $h(n)$ are both increasing functions, both $g(n)$ and $h(n)$ are integral valued step functions, and the increase of each step is just one. I'll show that $f_1(n)$ is a constant for $0 \le n \le 24$ by checking the end-points and each value of $n$ where $h(n)$ increases. At those points, I'll show that

$$8n + 13 = 25(h(n)) + r, \; \; 0 \le r \le 12 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

to confirm $g(n) = h(n)$ and $g(n-1) = g(n) - 1$.

For $0 \le n \le 16$, we have $h(n) = \left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{3}\right\rfloor$, and for $17 \le n \le 24$, we have $h(n) = \left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$. Next, $g(0) = h(0) = 0$ and

$$h(2) = 1, \; 8(2) + 13 = 25(1) + 4 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

For $n$ up to $16$, the value of $h(n)$ increases by $1$ for each increase in $n$ by $3$, with $8n + 13$ increasing by $8(3) = 25 - 1$ each time. This means $g(n)$ also increases by $1$, but with the value of $r$ decreasing by $1$ each time, starting from $4$ as indicated in \eqref{eq2A}. Thus, we get a match up to $h(14) = 5, \; 8(14) + 13 = 25(5) + 0$.

The next $h(n)$ increase is at $n = 18$, with $h(18) = 6, \; 8(18) + 13 = 25(6) + 7$. Thus, as discussed above, we'll continue to have matching increases with $g(21) = h(21)$ and $g(24) = h(24)$. This confirms $g(n) = h(n)$ for $0 \le n \le 24$.

---

**Note**: Since the remainder $r$ is $0$ at $n = 14$, the next increase in $h(n)$ must occur when $n$ increases by $4$ instead of $3$, with this accomplished by the increase in value of $\left\lfloor\frac{n-m}{25}\right\rfloor$ at $n = m$ for any $15 \le m \le 17$, not just $m = 17$ as used in the question.

Comment: Quite a nice solution! Thanks (+1)!

Answer (score 2):

Brute force won't be that hard.

We can uniquely write $n$ as $25k +r$ where $17\le r < 42$.

$[\frac {n-17}{25}] = [\frac {25k + (r-17)}{25}] = [k + \frac {r-17}{25}] = k$.

$[\frac {n-12-[\frac {n-17}{25}]}3]=[\frac {25k -12 + r -k}{3}]=[\frac {24k -12 +r}3]= [8k -4 +\frac r3]= 8k -4 + [\frac r3]$.

Meanwhile $[\frac {8n + 13}{25}]=[8k + \frac {8r+13}{25}]= 8k +[\frac {8r+13}{25}]$

And $[\frac {8n + 13}{25}]-[\frac {n-12-[\frac {n-17}{25}]}3]=[\frac {8r+13}{25}]-  [\frac r3]+4$

If suffices to prove that is constant for  $17 \le r < 42$.

Taking a single value, say $r=25$ (hey, I'm lazy) we have $[\frac {8r+13}{25} ]=[\frac {8\cdot 25+13}{25}]=8$ and $[\frac r3]=[\frac {25}3]=8$.

So $[\frac {8n + 13}{25}]-[\frac {n-12-[\frac {n-17}{25}]}3]=[\frac {8r+13}{25}]-  [\frac r3]+4= 8-8+4=4$.

So we need to show that for all $17\le r < 42$ that $[\frac {8r+13}{25}]-  [\frac r3]+4 =4$ or in other words that $[\frac r3] = [\frac {8r+13}{25}]$.

Let $[\frac r3] =m$ then $m \le \frac r3 < m+1$
$3m \le r < 3m + 3$
$24m + 13 \le 8r+13 < 24m + 37$
$\frac {24m + 13}{25} \le \frac {8r+13}{25} < \frac {24m + 37}{25}$
$m + (\frac {13}{25}- \frac 1{25}m) \le \frac {8r+12}{25} < (m+1) + (\frac {12}{25} -\frac 1{25}m)$.

If we can show $m \le m + (\frac {13}{25}- \frac 1{25}m) \le \frac {8r+12}{25} < (m+1) + (\frac {12}{25} -\frac 1{25}m)\le m+1$ we'd be golden.

Now $\frac 1{25}m > \frac {13}{25} \iff m> 13\iff m\ge 14  \iff 3m\ge 42$. but $3m\le r < 42$ so that never occurs.

So $\frac {13}{25}-\frac 1{25}m \ge 0$ and

So $m \le m + (\frac {13}{25}- \frac 1{25}m) \le \frac {8r+13}{25}$ always.

Unfortunately we can't do the same to show $(m+1) + (\frac {12}{25} -\frac 1{25}m)\le m+1$.

We do have  $\frac {12}{25}>\frac 1{25}m \iff m> 12\iff m\ge 39$ so $39 \le 3m \le r$ will occur when $r = 39, 40, 41$.

In these cases we must show $m+ 1 \le \frac {8r+12}{25} <  (m+1) + (\frac {12}{25} -\frac 1{25}m)$ does not occur in these cases. (in all other cases we will have $m \le \frac {8r+13}{25} < (m+1) + (\frac {12}{25} - \frac 1{25}m)\le m+1$)

$\frac {8r + 12}{25} \ge m+1\iff 8r\ge 25m+13\iff r \ge \frac {25}8m + \frac {13}8$ but But that would require $3m+1 < \frac{25}8m +\frac {13}8 \le r< 3m+3$ so $r=3m+2$.  But were are only concerned with cases where $r=39, 40, 41$ or in other words $r = 41; m = 13$ is the only case where we *might* have:

$m < m + (\frac {13}{25}- \frac 1{25}m)< (m+1) \le \frac {8r+12}{25} < (m+1) + (\frac {12}{25} -\frac 1{25}m)$

However $\frac {8\cdot 41 + 12}{25} = 13\frac {15}{25}< m+1$ so we do not have that contradiction.

Comment: Good Work! One suggestion. It seems that we can shorten the proof of $\left \lfloor \frac{r}{3}\rfloor = \lfloor \frac{8r+13}{25}\right \rfloor $ a bit. From $17 \le r \le 41$ and $3m \le r \le 3m+2$, we can deduce that $5 \le m \le 13$. We can then use this to deduce that $\left \lfloor \frac{8r+13}{25} \right\rfloor=m$

Comment: That's quite some work! Great (+1)!