Confused on answer given for the question: prove $\lceil\frac{n}{m}\rceil = \lfloor\frac{n+m-1}{m}\rfloor$

Here is the link to the problem and Mr. Andrew's solution:
1https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1281757/801877
Surprisingly, when trying to prove this problem I tried doing this exact way and got piecewise definition for ceiling(n/m), but I'm not sure how to do the last step of the proof here.
From what I understand, Mr. Andrews is just showing for case when
$r =/= 0$. I think I understand how I could manipulate the inequalities using what's given to get what he got by doing as follows:
$$0 < r < m$$
$$1 \leq < r < m$$
Add m to each part of inequality,
$$ m + 1 \leq r + m < 2m $$
$$ m + 1 \leq n - mq + m < 2m $$
Add mq to each part of inequality,
$$m + mq + 1 \leq n + m < 2m + mq$$
Subtract by 1,
$$ m + mq \leq n + m - 1 < 2m + mq - 1$$
Divide by m,
$$1 + q \leq \frac{n + m - 1}{m} < 2 + q - 1/m < q + 2$$
$$q + 1 \leq \frac{n + m - 1}{m} < q + 2$$
Hence  $\lceil\frac{n}{m}\rceil = \lfloor\frac{n+m-1}{m}\rfloor$ for r =/=0 case.
For r = 0 case, I get same inequality except instead of
"$q + 1 \leq$" I get "$q \leq$". However, I want the "$ < q + 1$" part as well to then show $\lceil\frac{n}{m}\rceil = \lfloor\frac{n+m-1}{m}\rfloor$ for r = 0 case too. How do I do that?

Just edited my question to be more clear. Kindly please check.

Bob, no need to open a new post 4 min after commenting below @ThomasAndrews' answer. He is still active and would probably have clarified.

But he didn't and still hasn't

For the $r=0$ case, using the same manipulations as yours:
$$0 = r < 1$$
Add $mq$ to each part of inequality,
Add $m$ to each part of inequality,
Subtract by $1$,
$$mq+m-1 = r + mq + m - 1 < 1 + mq + m -1\\
mq + m - 1 = n + m - 1 < mq+m$$
Divide by $m$,
$$q \le q + \frac {m-1}m = \frac{n+m-1}{m} < q+1$$
Hence $\left\lceil\frac{n}{m}\right\rceil = \left\lfloor\frac{n+m-1}{m}\right\rfloor$ for $r=0$ case.

How'd you think of adding mq + m - 1? What's the intuition for that?

@BobMarley As in your question, where you "Add $m$ to each part of inequality", then "Add $mq$ to each part of inequality", then "Subtract by $1$".

Ya I mean when I first did it based on Mr. Andrews answer, I first added m then subtracted 1 to get what he got. Then I thought of replacing r by n - mq hoping it might lead to something. After that then I thought of adding mq to inequality to just get n + m - 1 in the middle of inequality. Then dividing by m to get (n + m - 1)/m in middle of inequality. It just luckily turned out to be >= q + 1 and < q + 2... but it felt very non-intuitive and random, especially starting off with m > r > 0 and the first 2 steps since I was just trying to get what Mr. Andrews got

@BobMarley For my intuition, from the middle $r$, I added $mq+m-1$ to match $n+m-1$, the numerator of the RHS in question. This also uses the definition $n=mq+r$. But I can't speak for Thomas Andrews for their intuition.

From the division algorithm, $q = \frac{n-r}{m}$. If $1 \le r\le m-1$, then $$q+1 =\underbrace{ \frac{n+m-r}{m} \le \frac{n+m-1}{m}}_{\text{Take smallest } r} <  \frac{n+m-1}{m} + \underbrace{\frac{m+1-r}{m}}_{\text{positive}} = \frac{n+2m-r}{m}=q+2$$

Thanks Sam for the answer. It's not intuitive for me on how you thought of adding (m + 1 - r)/m though. Also, this was for the r =/=0 case. What about the r = 0 case. How'd we show for that?

Also, what are the little boxes underneath trying to refer to exactly, since there's a space between them for the "positive" part. Are you trying to single out (m + 1) and r there spearately?

I added that quantity because I wanted $q+2$ on the right side of the inequality. @BobMarley  If $r=0$ is possible, then $q+1 = \frac{n+m}{m} > \frac{n+m-1}{m}$

I am suggesting that if you have a number $x$, then $x+a>x$ as long as $a>0$. The number that I added is indeed positive because of the range of $r$.

Ok cool just making sure. It's just the multiple small boxes looks weird... and to be clear the "take smallest r" is just saying it'll be <= if we take smallest r which we let be 1 for r =/=0 case.

How is q + 1 = (n + m)/m ?

Wait nvm lol since we're just considering r = 0 my bad.
